# Getting the field(s) that caused a save changes exception in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've created a REST API in MVC3 and one the things I need to do is return a descriptive message when an update or create operation fails.

Messages like `"The update operation failed while creating the customer object."` isn't good enough.

My next thought was to get the message out of the exception which returns something like this:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Business_Category". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb_Dev", table "dbo.Category", column 'CategoryID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Which seems to be too much information. I could parse out `column "CategoryID"`out of the exception message... Not sure if that is reliable.

Is it possible to set up attributes for the fields so when they fail I can get that fields error description? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Exception.Data. More info can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Place the offending code in a try catch block.  Set a breakpoint somewhere in the catch section.  Then add a watch item called **ModelState**.

**ModelState.IsValid** will tell you if the model is valid (or errored).

**ModelState.Keys** will show you the list of fields the model contains.

**ModelState.Values** will show you the data values for each of those respective fields.  Drill down into each and you will see an **Errors** node with a count of how many errors are in that data item.  Look for the one with more than 0 errors.  Make a note of its index, and then go back to the **ModelState.Keys[Index noted]** to see which field is is causing the error.

To be honest, once you got this far, you'll have all the information you need to sort out any errors of this kind.  I'll leave it up to you know.